# How to stylize jQuery UI tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Back when the tooltip plugin was still outside of jQuery UI (bassistance?)

I was able to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#2087051").tooltip({
    bodyHandler: function() { return $($(this).attr("href")).html(); },
    showURL: false
});
</script>
<a href="#208705a" class="directory directory-person" id="2087051" onclick="javascript: window.location='main-display-staff-info.cfm?ouid=254924&telsumm_id=208705';">12992</a>

<div id="208705a" style="display:none;">
    <STRONG>Contact Details: <SPAN CLASS="directory directory-entity">Ms Debra Jones</SPAN></STRONG><BR CLASS="directory" />
    <BR CLASS="directory" />
    <LABEL CLASS="staffInfo">Telephone</LABEL>1653392&nbsp;<STRONG>(Internal)</STRONG><BR CLASS="directory" />
    <LABEL CLASS="staffInfo">Department</LABEL>Manchester University, Deputy Vice-Chancellor (Academic)<BR CLASS="directory" />
    <LABEL CLASS="staffInfo">Role</LABEL>Exec Assistant<BR CLASS="directory" />
    <LABEL CLASS="staffInfo">Building</LABEL>School of Medicine<BR CLASS="directory" />
    <LABEL CLASS="staffInfo">Room No</LABEL>2101<BR CLASS="directory" />
    <LABEL CLASS="staffInfo">Email</LABEL>myemail@email.com<BR CLASS="directory" />
    <BR CLASS="directory" />
    <strong>Click for email/website links</strong>
</div>
```

but with the tooltip being a part of jQuery UI, what I wrote above is not possible anymore.

This is how I'm doing it using jQuery UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip, {
        options: {
            content: function () {
                return $(this).prop('title');
            }
        }
    });
</script> 
<a href='#' class='208705 directory directory-person ' onclick='javascript: window.location='StaffInfo.html?id=208705';'>1234534992</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        $('.208705').attr('title', $('#208705a').remove().html());
    });
</script>
<div id='208705a' style='display:none;'>
    <div>
        <strong>Contact Details: <span class='directory directory-entity'>Ms Debra Jones</span></strong><br class='directory' /><br class='directory' />
        <label class='staffInfo'>Telephone</label>12122992<br class='directory' />
        <label class='staffInfo'>Department</label>Manchester University, Deputy Vice-Chancellor (Academic)<br class='directory' />
        <label class='staffInfo'>Role</label>Exec Assistant to Deputy VC Academic<br class='directory' />
        <label class='staffInfo'>Building</label>School of Medicine<br class='directory' />
        <label class='staffInfo'>Room No</label>233310<br class='directory' />
        <label class='staffInfo'>Email</label>myemail@email.com<br class='directory' /><br class='directory' />
        <strong>Click for email/website links</strong>
    </div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        $(document).tooltip();
    });
</script>
```

This is what it looks like using jQuery UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaIYx.jpg

This is what it looks like using the original plugin: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdW0p.jpg

I find I have greater control to styling on the old tooltip compared to the new one. As can be seen from the 2nd screenshot, my tooltip is using the correct font css that was set in one of my css file.

Can anyone suggest what I can do so I have greater control to styling when using tooltip via jQuery UI?

Thanks

Comment: Use the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to get the css you want. Also [here's](http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/) the class list.

Comment: And you also have [this](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css)